# What is an inexpensive camera for photographing LEGO?

Tags: afol

What is an inexpensive camera for taking pictures of LEGO? I currently use an iPad and I am not satisfied with the photo quality. I would prefer something 100$ or less, if possible.

Comment: photography questions here usually get migrated to photo.stackexchange.com. See [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16741/what-are-the-best-techniques-for-making-great-photographs-of-lego-creations) question for example.

Answer (score 5):

Lighting is key for any camera, but especially for the sensors in cell phones, tablets, and inexpensive point and shoots.

If you place your LEGOs in daylight or under a bright white LED / CFL you may find your iPad will do just fine.   Whereas, under normal room lighting the photos become a noisy mess.

Answer (score 1):

I've used pretty inexpensive point and shoot digital cameras to some degree of luck. But I also use a semi decent photo editing software to fix lighting and crop the image.

On my current LEGO Church Project build I've been using my Galaxy Tab Pro's camera which has a flash and it works rather well. Better than the cameras I had been using.

But the key as the other poster has pointed out. Lighting always makes things better. So a flash will help with that.